# My "code" for my radio-button does not work

Tags: radio-button

I have this Code for my radio-button:

```
 <p>
    <input type="radio" name="os" id="linux" value="Linux">
    <label for= "linux">Linux Distro</label>
    </p>
```

It shows "Linus Distro" but not the Radio-button for it.
Do you know why and how I can solve this problem?

Comment: If you have an error it's because of this part of your code as it's working correctly here : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzQKzx
We can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Do you have any clue where the problem could be?

Comment: From what you provided, no sorry. You still can check the page source to see if the radio button is in it, check if you have some css that hide it,...